# how to make categories section in mongoose schema design of product like electronics, fashion ,food, etc. help to build this type of model

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

How to make this type of model?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the text to your question and use the code format tool.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
category: {
    type: String,
    enum: {
        //Your categories
        value: ['electronics', 'food', 'fashion'],
        message: '{Value} //Your error message'
}
```

enum is validator in mongoose you can check it on their docs.

message -- this will warn user if he enters any other category not from value array

Before saving data mongoose will check if the provided category is in the categories of value array and will only save the data if category is on  of them. U can add more categories in the array if you want.

Comment: Thanks to give the better answer of my question